# Eclipse. Как настроить среду для Java, PHP, Python одновременно

Tags: php, java, python, eclipse

Здраствуйте, программирую на Java в Eclipse, сейчас стоит задача писать на php и python также, как настроить среду для 3 языков одновременно?
Нужно ли качать отдельные версии или можно настроить все в одном и строить проекты для разных языков

Answer (score 1):

Можно установить три разных среды, можно установить в одну среду разные плагины для разных языков. Как говорится "на вкус и цвет..." Надо только понимать, что чем больше плагинов вы установите в Eclipse, тем "толще" она станет, тем больше ресурсов потребуется для её запуска. ОЗУ, например. Но если ваш проект мультиязычный, т.е. в одном проекте используется сразу несколько языков, то, конечно, удобнее с таким проектом работать из одной IDE. В конечном счёте всё зависит от ваших личных предпочтений, возможностей вашего компьютера. Попробуйте оба варианта, выберите то, что вам больше понравится.

Answer (score 1):

Можно по-разному, но у меня стоит сборка Eclipse для основного языка, остальное добивается плагинами. Именно так потому, что если что-то пойдёт не так (а бывает), проще снести и/или переустановить плагины, не теряя основого функционала. А переключаться между проектами проще не выходя из IDE.

Что ещё может быть важно: не забыть проверить ассоциации файлов, чтобы файлы каждого типа открывались в своём редакторе (от этого зависит набор возможностей, связанных с языком). Не помешает плагин [Perspective Switcher](http://www.richinternet.de/blog/indexa36f.html?entry=1758AACF-910C-DE52-368E1421BEFDA19B) (автоматическое переключение перспектив в зависимости от типа файла), но это уже на любителя, и только после настройки ассоциаций.